NextJS Internal Server Error deployed in Kubernetes
I'm having a NextJS frontend application and NodeJS backend application. Both are deployed on Kubernetes. Frontend application Dockerfile looks like below.
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm i

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

EXPOSE 3000

And then Frontend application's next.config.mjs looks like below.
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // distDir: "build",
  images: {
    domains: ["localhost", "frontend-app-URL"],
  },
  compiler: {
    removeConsole: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  },
  async rewrites() {
    console.log("NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL:", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL); // Log to debug
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: `http://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

And inside .env file, I have
NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL="http://backend:9001"
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:3000/api"
NEXT_PUBLIC_URL="http://localhost:3000/"
NODE_ENV="development"

So NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL="http://backend:9001" is the Kubernetes service.
All the Kubernetes ingresses are set up and when I access the frontend login page using the URL it loads as expected. But when I provides the username and the password for the login page it shows below error:

POST https://my-url/api/login 500 (Internal Server
Error)
And when I see the pod logs it shows

mvp@0.1.0 start                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │ │ > next start
│ │
│ │    ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
│ │    - Local:        http://localhost:3000
│ │
│ │  ✓ Ready in 627ms
│ │ TypeError: Expected "9001" to be a string
│ │     at
/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/path-to-regexp/index.js:237:19
│ │     at prepareDestination
(/app/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/prepare-destination.js:209:18)
│ │     at handleRoute
(/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/resolve-routes.js:501:94)
│ │     at resolveRoutes
(/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/resolve-routes.js:539:34)
│ │     at process.processTicksAndRejections
(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
│ │     at async handleRequest
(/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:200:96)
│ │     at async requestHandlerImpl
(/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:366:13)
│ │     at async Server.requestListener
(/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13)


Also, I am passing the env vars in Kubernetes
  env:
        - name: NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL # backend URL
          value: "http://backend:9001"
        - name: NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT #
          value: "http://localhost:3000/api"
        - name: NEXT_PUBLIC_URL
          value: "https://my-frontend-url"
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: "production"

Edited:
ClusterIP service for frontend
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000

And Ingress for frontend
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my-url
      secretName: my-secret
  rules:
    - host: my-url
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend
                port:
                  number: 80

And ClusterIP for backend
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9001
      targetPort: 9001

And I have defined below in backend k8s deployment
  ports:
    - containerPort: 9001

And in frontend
  ports:
    - containerPort: 80


show kubernetes manifests. connection refused probably means your port mappings from ingress -> service -> pod don't match up

@grug.0 I have added Kubernetes manifests to the original question now

But I see the cluster ip service endpoints are correctly showing the IPs of the frontend pods

and for backend as well

dockerfile / frontend exposes :3000, service + containerPort is :80.

so service + containerport also should be 3000?

ingress.service.port.number == service.ports[x].port  ;  service.ports[x].targetPort == pod...containers[x].ports[x].containerPort  ;  pod...containers[x].ports[x].containerPort == dockerfile.expose

Okay now I get 500 Internal server error and when I check the pod logs it says "TypeError: Expected "9001" to be a string "

sounds like the issue you posted is solved, have a wonderful day!

r u using docker compose

Its not yet solved @grug.0 I get 500

@Yilmaz No Im using Kubernetes
